# Have visual studio break on exceptions only within certain calls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, visual-studio-debugging

I know how to make visual studio break on exceptions, and break on only certain types of exceptions.  Also I know already about "only my code"

Is there a way to configure it to do so only within certain code blocks (either blocks, or within a particular class/function?) Maybe some sort of pragma directive?

**NOTE : THIS IS TALKING ABOUT BREAKING ON EXCEPTIONS. NOT BREAKPOINTS**

Comment: Just because the answers don't meet EXACTLY what you want does not mean that they are completely unhelpful... You really shouldn't downvote unless people are way off. Just don't upvote.

Comment: Is this link useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh(v=vs.90).aspx?

Answer (score 0):

You can right click breakpoints and set conditions. For example, if I want to set a condition for a function to stop if the caller method was Main, you could use:

```
new StackFrame(1, true).GetMethod().Name == "Main"
```

[image]

Depending on what specific conditions you want your breakpoint to stop at, you could use that.

Comment: Not looking at breakpoints. Im talking about breaking on exceptions